# gradle 'dependencies.dependency.version' for is missing

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

Using the plugin `io.spring.dependency-management` , some of the versions of my dependencies are deducts from others dependencies with

```
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    }
}
```

Using `gradlew clean build install`

does install the jar with a pom that dosn't contains the version of many dependencies.

Running the build of another submodule that depends of the first JAR, result to :

```
Errors occurred while build effective model from C:\APPLIS\HELIOSDEV\repo\com\sfr\ext_ope\library_ext_ope_admin\
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\library_ext_ope_admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom:
'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.github.jhipster:jhipster-framework:jar 
is missing. in com.sfr.ext_ope:library_ext_ope_admin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

How to force the build to add the versions inside the generated pom ?

Answer (score 2):

Moving `dependencyManagement` section to `allprojects {}` instead of `subprojects {}` fixed same issue for my project on `io.spring.dependency-management:1.0.9.RELEASE`